# converting result set into user defined data structure in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

MongoDB database returns data in its own data structure. For instance, in following example, data is returned in `cursor`. My question is  "How can I convert this data structure into user defined data structure (e.g., Java List, structure ) ? "

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

        query.put("i", 71);

        cursor = coll.find(query);

        try {
            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Morphia is the library that does object mapping for mongodb: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/.

Comment: I am looking for a simple solution. I think  Morphia is bit tedious solution.

Comment: If I may ask, what about morphia is tedious? I find it to be quite straightforward. A different option for you is to choose a dynamic language in which case the result set comes back as a map. I've used mongo+clojure this way for example, which I think is nicer than the java+morphia approach.